# How to add download link from database on custom page template?

Tags: database, templates, wpdb

I used a variable in head tag

```
$download = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT realname FROM odm_data where id='$id'");
```

When I call it using

```
<a href="download.php?file=<?php $download ?>">Download</a>
```

then it doesn't work

Basically,I wanna download or urldecode a file from database using php on custom page template of wordpress

Comment: `odm_data` is not a standard WordPress table, and what does download.php do and where is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*you're expecting a single row result so better use $wpdb->get_row
..$id I guess it's numeric so dont'use quote*/

global $wpdb;
$download = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT realname FROM odm_data where id=".$id); 

<a href="download.php?file=<?php echo $download->realname ?>">Download</a>
```

Comment: how to set downloadable file path manually??
Because it respond me as "Page Not Found"

Comment: What's the output of  $download->realname? the path must correspond to a real and existing url, that means that 
- $download->realname must be something like http://www.example.com/your_download_dir/your_file.pdf
- the file exists in the "your_download_dir"

Comment: perhaps <a href="/download.php">(root link) instead of <a href="download.php">(relative link)

Comment: if $download->realname is only the name of the file you have to add something before such as `<?php echo home_url( '/' ).'your_download_dir/'. $download->realname ?>`

Comment: it's working ...